# How to host my INDEX.php main page and CRUD Application separately on the same domain

Tags: php

I am confused about hosting my CRUD Application and my website together.  How should I host my web-site in a way that any user can access it, but only users with permission can use my CRUD application?

Comment: any ideas or concepts are accepted!

Comment: Have you tried the Sub-folder method? Which we usually do for Admin.

Comment: @BessTilahun Please [edit] your question to include a description what a "CRUD application" is and how your main website is currently using your CRUD application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some simple options:

1) To use your Web page and your CRUD Application in same domain, use subfolders as shown below:

- `root/index.php`     (main-page)
- `root/subfolder/`   (CRUD Application)

The above method will work like below:

- `http://www.example.com` will load your `index.php`
- `http://www.example.com/subfolder/` will load your CRUD application

2) To protect your CRUD application:

- A normal *username* and *password* method will keep your pages safe from access.
- Basic Authentication also will keep your CRUD application folder safe from access.

Details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

Links on how to add Basic Authentication:

https://www.howtoforge.com/htaccess_authentication

https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-list/2005-June/msg04166.html